Long running spark job optimization
I have a UDF in Spark which calls an API to get the data for each city and state to get the postcode as a result. It is taking forever to complete the job. Please suggest an alternative for this code.
Code:
# Function to fetch zip code
def fetch(city, state):
    url = f"http://api.zippopotam.us/us/{state}/{city.replace(' ', '%20')}"
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        return data['places'][0]['post code'] if 'places' in data else None
    return None

# Register the UDF
fetchUDF = spark.udf.register("fetch", fetch, StringType())

# Load the dataframes
citiesDF = spark.read.parquet(citiesPath).select("city_id", "city", "state_abv")
trxDF = spark.read.parquet(trxPath)

# Perform the join and transformation
finalDF = (trxDF.join(broadcast(citiesDF), "city_id")
           .filter(col("state_abv").isNotNull())
           .withColumn("zip_code", fetchUDF(col("city"), col("state_abv"))))

# Write the result to disk partitioned by zip_code
finalDF.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("zip_code").parquet(finalPath)

I wanted to optimize the code to improve performance.

Are you making a call for each record? Maybe you can store the zip codes in advance and then join.

@Memristor is correct. Fetch all the postcodes in bulk using the API to make a lookup table and then perform a join using that lookup table instead.
